# How to remove remote url from Github repository

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I'm sure this is a super simple question but I wasn't able to find an answer to it, so I'm extremely grateful for your answers!

I have created a boilerplate repository that I (and anybody else) can copy as a starting point for a new project. Here's the problem: when I upload that repository to Github, I obviously need to set the remote URL. However, when someone (me, for example) clones the repository and makes changes, it's easy to push the changes without setting up your own URL, and therefore push changes to the original boilerplate.

How can I remove the remote URL from the repository and still host it on Github?

Comment: Make this a read-only repository so people can clone it but cannot push to it?

Comment: The `git clone` operation will add a remote named origin with whatever URI was used in the clone operation. This is not stored in the repo on the server, only on the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remote isn't set *on* GitHub; it's set when you clone. Cloning sets up a remote, [called `origin` by default](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt--oltnamegt), that points to the URL you used to clone.

A few options:

1. **Don't clone in the first place.**

   You can create an empty repository and then pull from the source repository without setting a remote:

   ```
   git init foo
   cd foo
   git pull https://some.tld/foo/bar
   ```

   To make this easier, you could create an [alias](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-alias) that does it all in one go, e.g. by adding something like this to your `~/.gitconfig`:

   ```
   [alias]
       clone-template = "!f() { git init \"$2\" && git -C \"$2\" pull \"$1\"; }; f"
   ```

   Then you'd use it like this:

   ```
   git clone-template https://some.tld/foo/bar foo
   ```

   where `foo` is the local directory name you'd like to use.
2. **Clone and then remove the `origin` remote:**

   ```
   git clone https://some.tld/foo/bar
   cd bar
   git remote remove origin
   ```

   To make this easier, you could create an alias that does both operations, as above.

   The tricky part there is knowing the name of the directory that was created by the clone so you can `cd` into it. The alias above requires the local directory as an argument to get around this.
3. **Use a third-party tool like [`degit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/degit) that clones without history.**

   The main disadvantages here are (a) having a third-party dependency, possibly using a dev stack you don't want to set up, and (b) losing all commit history as well as the remote.

   You can mitigate against (a) by doing something like `git clone --depth=1` followed by removing the `.git/` directory, but this will still nuke all your history. If you're going to do this, I suggest you just unset the `origin` as in the second option.

Answer (score 1):

check this command

```
 git remote remove origin
```

Comment: Ahm Sf I i remove remote, how can I then update that change to the remote repository in Github?

Comment: did get your point, why do you need to remove remote url and still you need to send update to github?

Comment: I'd like to have my Github repository to be available to clone, but I do not want to have cloned versions to get pushed into it, if that makes sense?

Comment: Chris I salute you! Thanks a lot, that was really useful. To be honest, I wasn't aware of pull method, will use that from now on!